# CEL 12, 21, and 55 on '94 Jeep Grand Cherokee

Tags: jeep, cel, grand-cherokee, obd-i

So, I've pulled the codes from my car based on the helpful information provided here:

[Check Engine Light on '94 Jeep Grand Cherokee](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/1182/78)

Now, I need just a little help understanding what the codes actually mean.  The translations below are taken directly from the other thread.

`12 memory to controller has been cleared within 50-100 engine starts`

What particular "memory" is this referring to, and how would it have been cleared?  I imagine loss of battery power would be one cause.  Is this also the same as the engine code memory?  Does that memory get cleared each time it's read?

`21 oxygen sensor signal, neither rich or lean detected`

I presume this is pretty straight-forward:  Check/replace O<sup>2</sup> sensors.  Although it could sort of be construed to mean that the air/fuel mix is dead-on, I'm sure that's not very likely.

`55 end of message`

I'm guessing I should see this every time I pull codes?  Sort of like this message from the MCP:

[image: END OF LINE]

Note:  This is for a '94 Jeep Grand Cherokee, 4WD, 4.0L in-line 6 cylinder engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this:

http://www.justanswer.com/chrysler/1l50u-does-dtc-12-memory-controller-cleared-within.html

Which seems to confirm that 12 just means the battery was disconnected and that you should always see 55.

21 should not come up unless there is a problem, because the sensor should be able to detect rich or lean.  So check/replace O2 is the correct course of action.