# CEL Code 41 on '94 Jeep Grand Cherokee

Tags: electrical, jeep, grand-cherokee

According to [this answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/1183/78) a CEL code of 41 means:

> charging system circuit not responding to control signal

What are likely causes of this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this means the regulator is going out of the alternator, but not sure. The code I saw for a 94 Jeep says, "Fault in the charging system or no field current." Could be several things, but thinking you need to get your alternator load tested. I believe an AutoZone, Checkers, O'Reilly, or Advanced Auto can do this for you.

It could also be that the field wire (goes from battery to the back of the alternator ... should be red) may not be connecting correctly. Check this on both ends for any type of corrosion. Also ensure this wire doesn't have any bulges in it (fat areas in the wire). If you see this, it's a bit of corrosion building up inside the wire and will cause enough resistance to subside the flow of electricity.